# How to realize load balancing for varnish servers with caching requests to backend(varnish servers)?

Tags: nginx, video, varnish, haproxy, high-load

Please use this pic to understand it clearly
[Architecture as I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwWLP.png)
Need to realize request caching at [balancer] level for VoD service.

When **reqst1** for **file1** is come to **balancer** it send it by round-robin to **varnish1** server and save this request to **local db/cache** etc.

Next **if varnish1** hasn't this file at cache it **send request to local webserver** (nginx-VOD1) and after that nginx got **file1** from fs for **varnish1**.

So if the next request is for **file1** balancer directly redirect it to **varnish1** so the info at the varnishes doesn't double.

So the root of issue next: how to realize this scheme or how to realize the other scheme in such way - **the content doesnt double at different varnish caches**?

1)Is there ready free/pay solution?

2)Is this scheme justified?

3)What I should use as balancer(nginx, haproxy, varnish)?

4)Where varnish should save it cache at ssd or at memmory?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)?  It seems to do much of what you're depicting, minimal config required, and only charges for bandwidth -- not storage -- so the size of the cache doesn't matter.  Since you appear to be unfamiliar with exactly how to engineer this, it might be a better option.   Google Cloud CDN and CloudFlare are similar services.

Comment: Thanks  Michael. Is these services is DMCA ignored? )

Comment: There are no legitimate service providers that ignore laws and regulations related to intellectual property rights... so, no, it is not "DMCA ignored."

Answer (score 1):

I think your schema is too complex and does not optimize the varnish cache.

I propose to simplify it by putting only one server varnish (bigger) which distributed the requests on the 4 backend.